# How do I query all fields in square-cube?

Tags: square-cube

I can run:

```
curl 'http://localhost:1081/1.0/event?expression=cube_request(path)&limit=1'
```

but this gives me only 'path'. I'd like to see a full record in my 'cube explorer' tool. Is there an * character that allows to effectively do a SELECT *? Or perhaps some other API?

I could always dig into the mongo backend, but perhaps there's a way to do this via the evaluator service.

Comment: Diving into the MongoDB appears to be the only way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

> curl
>   [http://localhost:1081/1.0/event?expression=type_sent_by_cube_emitter(field1,field2,...)]

but NOTE:

```
emitter.send({
   type:type_sent_by_cube_emitter,
   time:new Date().toISOString,
   data:something_string_or_Objects })
```

is CORRECT!

```
emitter.send({
   'type':type_sent_by_cube_emitter,
   'time':new Date().toISOString(),
   'data':something_string_or_Objects })
```

will return nothing if you want to use curl or browser to get data from cube's evaluator.